# Ugly scrollbar shown on HNQ when user image can't be shown

Tags: bug, design, user-interface, hot-questions

It appears that when a user image can't be displayed, the user in the Users List on the right side of the HNQ page gets a scrollbar:

[image: Ugly scrollbar]

Looking at [that user's profile](https://latin.stackexchange.com/users/3568/sacha-t-red), it looks like the link for the image it's trying to pull is:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/1562342057384865/picture?type=large
```

For me at least, visiting that page results in:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '1562342057384865' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100,
      "error_subcode": 33,
      "fbtrace_id": "DGmWtgYaB0R"
   }
}
```

I'm using Chrome Version 72.0.3626.121 (Official Build) (64-bit) on a Windows 10 machine.

Can we handle this better to avoid the strange scrollbar?

Comment: What would better handling look like? Keep the broken image, but don't show a scrollbar? Replace the broken image with a default avatar? Something else? Technically nothing is broken at the SE site. The user has chosen to break their user profile....

Comment: @rene I'm thinking change the broken avatar to something that will fit in that box, yes. Right now it looks like the "broken picture" image is shown with the user's name underneath. I think it'd suffice to just show the "broken picture" image in this case since the user's name is right next to it anyways.