# Alt text overlap for Top Network Askers with broken avatar

Tags: bug, design, stackexchange.com, gravatar, alt-text

When a user's avatar is not available, and they're listed in the Top Network Askers in the right sidebar of https://stackexchange.com/, the alt text of the avatar overlaps the username or site name in some browsers:

[image]
[image]
(left: Chrome, right: Firefox, both on macOS Catalina)

Comment: Well, tried to dig into it, the current design force a very small image, can't see a simple way to make room for alt text which isn't very short. I'm afraid this can be fixed only as part of a bigger design change of the page, or at least the Top Network Askers part of the page.

Comment: Related: [Ugly scrollbar shown on HNQ when user image can't be shown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325242/232439)

Answer (score 2):

We're not *supposed* to have alt text on the avatars. It causes all sorts of issues in all sorts of browsing configurations, because that's not what alt text is for. Specifically, [we should have `alt=""` set on them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379431/308065). See [the Web Accessibility Initiative guidance](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/images/decorative/):

> Decorative images don’t add information to the content of a page. For example, the information provided by the image might already be given using adjacent text, or the image might be included to make the website more visually attractive.
>
> In these cases, a null (empty) `alt` text should be provided (`alt=""`) so that they can be ignored by assistive technologies, such as screen readers.

User profile pages, and the hover cards, are a different case: people sometimes discuss profile pictures, so it would be nice to be able to *provide* alt text for that case. But that would be a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

"wizzwizz4's user avatar" is not acceptable in any case.