# CSS breaking on Top Answer User list for long names

Tags: bug, design, top-answers

I spotted that CSS is breaking on Top Answer User list for long names.
The image is not rendered and long names are causing a small scrolling section.

[image]

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is more caused by the avatar that doesn't load; the long username is simply incidental.

Comment: Duplicate of [Ugly scrollbar shown on HNQ when user image can't be shown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325242/ugly-scrollbar-shown-on-hnq-when-user-image-cant-be-shown).